# Is there a solution to insert a mysql rec and delete the old rec with same key automatically

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-delete

I have a MySQL Table with an index to field `symbol`and `tradedate`. Is there a way to delete the older row automatically when `symbol`and `tradedate` is already in the table? I do know that I can make a UNIQUE index but then there comes an error. I do not want to make a loop in my php file for each symbol x tradedate and delete it in the loop when its already in the table. It takes to long. I have to import 5000 rows per day. The reason is to prevent dublicates. Thanks

Comment: Are you doing `INSERT`? So, maybe `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: Have you considered setting a unique key on symbol and tradedate and using insert..on duplicate key?

Comment: @tcadidot0 yes I do insert from another table. how is this insert ignore done`?

Comment: P.Salmon. How can I make insert on dublicate key? I can make a unique key on symbol and tradedate. found this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/  THANKS a lot!

Comment: Let me understand again, 1) your operation consists of inserting data from table A to B and 2) you don't want to insert table A data that already existed in table B, is that correct?

Comment: @tcadidot0 thanks I did it with this way now. `insert into locMarketCAP (country, ..) (SELECT ss.country, Now() as importdatetime,  ...   from (select * from aktien where tradedate = ( Select max(TradeDate) from aktien kk where kk.country = 'US')  ) ss  join  rr on ss.country = rr.localcurrencyCountry where ( ss.country = 'US' ) order by ss.TradeDate desc) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE       country = ss.country,   importdatetime = Now(),  ... ;` thanks a lot!

Comment: I see you take @P.Salmon suggestion. Glad it worked out for you. ;)

Comment: @tcadidot0 I also need your advice to move one table to the other without duplicates. I had in the originate table dups in it so I could not make a unique index. THANKS also to you.